# How can I get an ng-content select filter to work with projected template content?

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have a `List` component that's used to render a list. (Well, I don't, but I've tried to distil my problem down into a noddy example that's easy to understand).

The template for the `List` component has one or more `ListItem` components that allow the list items to be defined, like this:

```
<app-list>
  <app-list-item text='foo'></app-list-item>
  <app-list-item text='bar'></app-list-item>
</app-list>
```

...which should be rendered as:

> - foo
> - bar

I also have (let's pretend) a `Reminder` component that makes use of the `List` component. The `Reminder` component has a `deadline` property, and the list of things to do by this deadline is defined in the component's template, using one or more of the `ListItem` components we saw earlier:

```
<app-reminder deadline='Today'>
  <app-list-item text='foo'></app-list-item>
  <app-list-item text='bar'></app-list-item>
</app-reminder>
```

This should be rendered as:

> Remember to do the following by Today:
>
> - foo
> - bar

The `List` component is very simple:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: `
    <ul>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </ul>
  `
})
export class ListComponent{
  @ContentChildren(ListItemComponent) public readonly items: QueryList<ListItemComponent>;
}
```

The `ListItem` component is even simpler:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list-item',
  template: '<li>{{text}}</li>'
})
export class ListItemComponent {
  @Input() public text;
}
```

Finally, the `Reminder` component is pretty simple too:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reminder',
  template: `
    <h2>Remeber to do the following by {{deadline}}</h2>
    <app-list>
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </app-list>
  `
})
export class ReminderComponent {
  @Input() public deadline: string;
}
```

Using these components with the template snippets shown above works fine. You can see this in action in [this StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p97qrg).

Now to the main point of the question. Both the `List` component and the `Reminder` component use `<ng-content>`. In both cases, we don't really want to project *all* content into the list - just the `<app-list-item>` elements.

If I change the `<ng-content>` tag in the template for the `Reminder` component like so:

```
<ng-content select='app-list-item'></ng-content>
```

...then the component still works, and excludes any additional content in its template, which is what we want.

If I make the same change to the `<ng-content>` tag in the template for the `List` component, that also works for a simple template like this:

```
<app-list>
  <app-list-item text='foo'></app-list-item>
  <app-list-item text='bar'></app-list-item>
  <h1>EXCLUDE ME</h1>
</app-list>
```

**However**, that last change (adding a `select` filter to the `<ng-content>` element in the `List` component's template) stops the `Reminder` component from working. No list items are rendered in the reminder.

I imagine that this might be because the `List` component that's rendered by the `Reminder` component's template sees the *rendered* content (`<li>` tags) rather than the *template* content (`<app-list-item>` tags).

It seems that I have an unpleasant choice here - I can either *not* restrict the type of content that will be rendered by the `List` component (in which case any old junk might get included), or lose the ability to use the `List` component when creating other components.

Or am I missing something? Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You could define the select-filter inside the `ListComponent` like this, to account for nested content projection: `<ng-content select='app-list-item,ng-content'>`. It works, but I am really unsure if it is a good idea to do it like that.

Comment: @Drenai: forked StackBlitz showing what happens when I add a filter to `<ng-content>` in the template for the `List` component: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mkxq2b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I managed to solve this by using [ngProjectAs](https://medium.com/claritydesignsystem/ng-content-the-hidden-docs-96a29d70d11b).

#### reminder.component.ts

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-reminder',
  template: `
    <h2>Remeber to do the following by {{deadline}}</h2>
    <app-list>
      <ng-container ngProjectAs="'app-list-item'">
        <ng-content select='app-list-item'></ng-content>
      </ng-container>
    </app-list>
  `
})
export class ReminderComponent {
  @Input() public deadline: string;
}
```

[Here is the StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k85wqd?file=src/app/reminder.component.ts).

Comment: Fantastic - that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I've never seen `ngProjectAs` being used before - thanks for posting the article link too

Comment: @Andrei Gatej - could you please explain how ngProjectAs solved this issue - I got the problem but how it is resolved using ngProjectAs still not getting.

Comment: @shrey here is another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58574420/9632621) which describes `ngProjectAs`. Things might have changed since 2019, so I'm not sure it will work the same now.

Comment: @AndreiGătej - what  I am trying to say is, could you please explain by enclosing <ng-content> in reminder component with this code 
 <ng-container ngProjectAs="'app-list-item'">

how it starts rendering perfectly?
I am not getting , how after adding ngProjectAs its work perfectly.

Comment: @shrey by using the `select` attribute on the `ng-content` tag, you're essentially mentioning which children to include when you're using the `remainder` tag like this: `<remainder><child></child></remainder>`. In the `remainder` component, the selected content is to be used into another component, i.e. `app-list`. In this case, the content means multiple children that have been passed to `remainder` and hence `ngProjectAs` is used to project all of them, without redundant wrapper elements.