# When should I use "ngProjectAs" attribute?

Tags: angular, typescript

I've come across the following code where `ngProjectAs` attribute is being used within `ng-container`. what is it used for, what problem does it address?

```html
<mat-form-field [formGroup]="group">
  <input matInput [formControlName]="field.name">

  <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of field.validations;" ngProjectAs="mat-error">
    <mat-error *ngIf="group.get(field.name).hasError(validation.name)">{{validation.message}}</mat-error>
  </ng-container>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Great question and I think the answer is actually not providing an explanation on when to use `ngProjectAs` and when to use a simple attribute for projecting content.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I find `ngProjectAs` useful when I want to project an `ng-container` under a certain selector.

*[Here](https://dev.to/anduser96/angular-a-use-case-for-ngprojectas-pnj) you can find a short article about it.*

Imagine you have this this component:

```js
@Component({
 selector: 'awesome-comp',
 template: `
  <ng-content select="[foo]"></ng-content>
 `
})
export class AwesomeComponent { }
```

#### consumer.component.html

As you know, this is how you'd project content inside `awesome-component`:

```html
<awesome-comp>
 <p>Hello there!</p> 
</awesome-comp>
```

But what happens when you want to project **more elements/components** under the same selector?

One way(not really recommended) would be to do this:

```html
<awesome-comp>
 <div foo>
  <h1> <!-- ... --> </h1>
   <p> <!-- ... --> </p>
 </div> 
</awesome-comp>
```

As you can see, we're adding a **redundant** div in order to be able to project multiple elements.

Now, here is how `ngProjectAs` saves the day:

```html
<awesome-comp>
 <ng-container ngProjectAs='[foo]'>
  <h1> <!-- ... --> </h1>
   <p> <!-- ... --> </p>
 </ng-container> 
</awesome-comp>
```

The above snippet won't add any redundant wrapper elements.

Comment: There is also this great article explaining the detailed use of `*ngProjectAs`
https://medium.com/ignite-ui/using-ng-content-ngprojectas-1664d7c1d3b

Comment: I don't get it, as just using `<ng-container foo>` seems to have the same output.

Comment: @Steve Maybe it depends on which version you're using, back then it was Angular 7-8, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Steve, you're right; `<ng-container foo>` works, but if you were using a class selector like `<ng-content select=".foo"></content>` then `<ng-container class=".foo">` does not work, whereas `<ng-container ngProjectAs=".foo">` does. It also allows for more complicated projections such as `<ng-container ngProjectAs="div.foo:not(.bar)">`

Comment: @Ronnie The reason `<ng-container class=".foo">` doesn't work is because it should be `<ng-container class="foo">`. Notice how I removed the dot that shouldn't have been there in the first place. That dot is meant to specify elements with that CSS class in a CSS selector. You don't include the dot in the `class` attribute.

Comment: You write in your answer: "One way(not really recommended) would be to do this", As a reason you write that it adds a redundant div. But as @Steve mentions in his comment it works fine with a `ng-container` element. 
Are there any other reasons why you would recommend against this way of projecting content? If not then I think your much upvoted answer is actually not answering the question...

Comment: @Wilt Back then, in 2019, IIRC, the only way was `ngProjectAs`. Things might have changed throughout these years. Right now my main focus is not Angular, so I wouldn't know how to answer your question. Also, @Ronnie points out a different use case.

Comment: @AndreiGătej Thanks for your comment. I just checked my Git history, and it seems I have been using Angular and content projection with attributes on `ng-container` elements without `*ngProjectAs` successfully already since at least 2018. It seems like both works fine, but using `ngProjectAs` is simply not necessary in simple content projections.

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned by @Junaid in his comment on the other answer there is [a great post on medium](https://medium.com/ignite-ui/using-ng-content-ngprojectas-1664d7c1d3b) with a complex content projection example when you MUST use `*ngProjectAs` for making content projection work properly.

The "**redundant** `div`" as mentioned in the other answer is not a valid reason, since content projection can be also done with an `ng-container` element (I commonly use `ng-container` elements for [multi-slot content projection](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#multi-slot-content-projection)).

In other words this works fine (and no redundant elements are added):

```
<awesome-comp>
  <ng-container foo>
    <h1> <!-- ... --> </h1>
    <p> <!-- ... --> </p>
  </ng-container> 
</awesome-comp>
```

---

In most cases content projection with a simple content selecting attribute works fine. 
Using `*ngProjectAs` is really only needed in some some more complex edge cases. This is also mentioned inside [the Angular documentation on content projection here](https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#projecting-content-in-more-complex-environments):

> In some cases, you might want to project content as a different element. For example, the content you want to project might be a child of another element. Accomplish this with the `ngProjectAs` attribute.

So in other words; just use a simple attribute for your content projection and when you cannot get your content projection to work it is maybe time to deep dive into the example and documentation mentioned above.