# How to use ng-content with an ng-container?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am not getting my components to display when they are within an `ng-container`. I have an array of items that I am looping over where each item has a boolean value of whether or not the user can see the item based on their access. Since I cannot place two structural directives on an element I decided to use an `ng-container` for the `ngFor` and then place the `ngIf` on the component.

This is the primary side nav component which displays a list of side nav items.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'side-nav',
  template: '<ng-content select="side-nav-item"></ng-content>'
})
export class SideNav { }
```

This is an example side nav item (for this purpose it does nothing except display an h2):

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'side-nav-item',
  template: '<h2>Side Nav Item</h2>'
})
export class SideNavItem { }
```

This utilizes the two above components

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'main-nav',
  template: `
    <side-nav>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of sideNavItems">
        <side-nav-item *ngIf="item.hasAccess"></side-nav-item>
      </ng-container>
    </side-nav>

    <side-nav>
      <side-nav-item *ngFor="let item of sideNavItems"></side-nav-item>
    </side-nav>
  `
})
export class MainNav {
  sideNavItems: ISidNavItem[] = [
    {
      hasAccess: true, uri: '/dashboard'
    }
  ]
}
```

In this [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rvlrvb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I would like to see two components printed, but I am only getting the last one because it is not inside of an `ng-container`. How can I get this working using this `ngFor` and `ngIf`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ngProjectAs` in your `MainNav` template.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-nav',
  template: `
    <side-nav>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let item of sideNavItems" ngProjectAs="side-nav-item">
        <side-nav-item *ngIf="item.hasAccess"></side-nav-item>
      </ng-container>
    </side-nav>

    <side-nav>
      <side-nav-item *ngFor="let item of sideNavItems"></side-nav-item>
    </side-nav>
  `
})
export class MainNav {
  sideNavItems: ISidNavItem[] = [
    {
      hasAccess: true, uri: '/dashboard'
    }
  ]
}
```

This way the `select` of the `ng-content` will read the `ng-container` as a `side-nav-item`.

Comment: Here's more about ngProjectAs's usefulness: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58574420/1772933